# Setting up an OpenGL ES renderer for 2D?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, perspective, renderer

I'm trying to set up the renderer so that regardless of device, the view is a simple 2D field with the top of the screen at 1.0f and the bottom at -1.0f. I can't seem to get it quite right, I've been using the below method in the onSurfaceChanged() method and playing with the parameters in gluPerspective to achieve the desired effect, but it seems impossible to make perfect. Surely there is an alternative way to go about this to achieve what i'm after. I've also been playing with the Z values of the meshes drawn to try to get them to match.

Again i'm trying to set it up so that the screen is defined in the range -1.0f to 1.0, so that if you drew a square with sides equal to 2.0f it would fill the entire screen regardless of aspect ratio. What do I need to change to do this? (include the value I should use for the Z dimension of the mesh vertices)

(Don't be alarmed by the strange parameters in gluperspective(), I've been tinkering to see what happens.)

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
            height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
        }

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 90.0f, (float) width / (float) height,
                    0.0000001f, 100.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a Ortho Matrix instead:

```
Matrix.orthoM(projectionMatrix,0,-yourdisplayWidth/2,+yourdisplayWidth/2,-yourdisplayHeight/2,+yourdisplayHeight/2,0f,2f);
```

So you can place your image-quads in distance of 1f in front of your camera. You also have to size your quads as big as they are in pixels. This way you can render pixelperfect.

See also: https://github.com/Chrise55/Llama3D

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try experimenting with using [glOrtho](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glOrtho.html) or [glFrustum](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glFrustum.html) instead of glPerspective